# Filtering concated charts using legend in Vega-Lite

Tags: selection, legend, vega-lite

I hit a snag trying to create two `concat`-ed charts filtered by legend (`selection.bind = "legend"`).

After a bit of head scratching I was able to reduce the issue to the following (this is based on one of the examples in the documentation):

1. [Example 1 - works as expected](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-oDgZSwY0dclobCbncoEiUeiJtjcfiVGHlYbIGTo6DqYrbfTGcyeUqpSnhuVFvLxUqfgWlNxUPFNabLaFe2aNFMQNsgA) - clicking a cylinder number on
   the legend filters the display on the left chart. (I did not
   implement any filtering for the chart on the right.)
2. [Example 2 - does not work](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoAWOgCtY3AHaQANOCgATdHkw5gkVgCcx2LTvSl46I7HmKVAX3VgNkeMut5IYHAG0NCFAIEKgMIwBrM0hCbkYlb3VAkMhkJQ9NeOozYNCUgA8cyAAzRmQxTWiACW5bZFiAd2QjNSg8AE9CZGiAR1Z0BOYdRipIZ2TQyHai0vLKnEgAWUYxZFgAfS6jdYBxdDExZVbIDq7e-sHdPBHu8byU7kJ0eGZp-Qm8krKK6IBhdokSk0zVgag+k1O3QWSm4qHi+0g4LAjg+KNCdxCuUm4SiC1i8USH0gsHKyHg1yO73u2Pa-wkOSREBOnShYVYYmuYOpKVmFVB-kgdPiwNskAAui5uVB2MLoqtqGlKki0XkMZM0hksgzuZBCvovnNqrUSY1msdIecBtcrjcxpL7lMZt95lBlqsNltdvtDipVG0WZbLsNRmrPo9nq9tVL3MpMhSVFSpUySatyTwE2FaQDGFyk1BeS7BdmgSDc0nmWcFrVMkoEYzkfbqZAKPtWKyAAzK1HJFVikAooA) - Here I have just swapped the two charts.
   I was assuming that now the chart on the right would become interactive 
   (that is it will be filtered after clicking the legend). This does not work.

Is it a bug or am I misunderstanding some basic concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two charts sharing the same legend, and two different legend specifications (one interactive, one not). When you concatenate two charts, Vega-Lite shares scales and legends by default, meaning that it has to choose one of the legend specifications to honor, and one to ignore. The choice the library makes is to honor the first and ignore the second. This is why the legend reflects whatever is specified in the left-most chart of your specification.

The way around this is to set the legend color resolve to independent, so each chart specifies its own legend, and to explicitly set the legend to null to hide it for the chart you don't want a legend for. Modifying your second example ([open in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoAWOgCtY3AHaQANOCgATdHkw5gkVgCcx2LTvSl46I7HmKVAX3URI8ZdbxmA2hoigIQKgMIwBrM0hCbkYlLxcgqGQld00Y6jMAhNcADwzIADNGZDFNCIAJbltkKIB3ZCM1KDwAT0JkCIBHVnRY5h1GKkhnPwTIZrzC4tKcSABZRjFkWAB9NqNlgHF0MTFlRsgWts7u3t08AfbhrNduQnR4ZnH9AqKSiIBhZoklTXrYfcO7RmSm4qBi232i2oSWmYCUrB2jhGECRQSugUyQUgIXCMyiMTiyKgsGKyHg5z2+iJrlQzU+EjygIiqAR532kxK-xw3kg9Jiv1skAAuqooOx+REoTChkT0Vikik0hlqVBcs8ObDIBUqrV6gDWkCoF0euczhchvEsmMJq9NfNFis1pttrsVKKDgbjia+udBnLRrd7o9lddAm5lKkKSoqaGsSTFuSeNHgnSvow1CqsRqPmmfn8M7Gw0yZpVUkoIZmwP6rRRtqxDQAGFWohItlEaEUaSBGJbcMSDZ5Sn55QMPFoRfnVGFJLyOJGOIA)):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "data": {"url": "data/cars.json"},
  "concat": [
    {
      "mark": "point",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "Horsepower", "type": "quantitative"},
        "y": {"field": "Miles_per_Gallon", "type": "quantitative"},
        "opacity": {"field": "Cylinders", "type": "nominal", "legend": null}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": "point",
      "selection": {
        "myCyli": {"type": "multi", "fields": ["Cylinders"], "bind": "legend"}
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "Horsepower", "type": "quantitative"},
        "y": {"field": "Miles_per_Gallon", "type": "quantitative"},
        "opacity": {
          "condition": {
            "selection": "myCyli",
            "field": "Cylinders",
            "type": "ordinal"
          },
          "value": 0
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "resolve": {"legend": {"opacity": "independent"}}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I was guessing there was something amiss with the legends because at some point I managed to display two of them. (I think it happens when you add a `transform` / `filter` block inside one of the `concat` objects.)
Side issue - if Vega-lite chooses one of the legend specifications to honor, shouldn't that trigger a message in the console?